# The best way to actively develop an NPM package that's consumed by another app running locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm currently working on a React application that's consuming a React library we also develop.

Currently, the process is to copy over the `dist` folder of the library over to the `node_modules` folder of the application.

To resolve the tedious nature of this, I thought the solution would be simple: to `npm link` the package in our application, and have the JSX/React components run through the application's `babel-loader`. That way, we'd also get webpack's dev server to watch for changes in the library and refresh automatically.

The problem with this is that the library's babel settings are different from those of the consuming application. For instance, root imports in the library (e.g. `import ~/some-module`) are supposed to resolve from the root folder *of the library*, but instead, they resolve to the root folder *of the application*, resulting in errors, because the only babel configuration it uses is the `.babelrc` from the application.

I tried adding separate webpack config rules to make exceptions for the library, but now it feels kind of hacky. In addition to that, the webpack dev server runs incredibly slow to boot up, presumably because it's running a babel transformation on the library too.

Is there an easier way to do this? Like telling webpack that "for this library in node_modules, use its own configuration file, and respect all of its own babel settings and relative imports?"

Comment: Since you are already `npm link`-ing, I am deleting my answer.  I'm not sure of a clean way to get this working.  I would think that consumed modules would be in a final state to be consumed.  If you want to conditionally watch and rebuild the library **by the consumer** module, then you will have to have some specialized build rules.